# Using Mahout to train an LDA and retrieve it's topics

Tags: mahout, lda, topic-modeling

I'm trying out Apache Mahout and there's a lot of information on how to use LDA to generate the topic model, there is however little information on how to do the same using their new CVB lda algorithm. What I want to do is generate probabilities for words to topics similarly to the original `ldatopic`.

Any information or an example as to how to do this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

UPDATE:

**Ok, so I worked out a fair bit of this, but it's still incomplete, so any help would be great!**

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I still don't know how to output the topics, but I have worked out how to get the cvb and what I think are the document vectors, however I'm not having any luck dumping them, so help here would still be appreciated!

Oh and don't forget to set the value of:

```
export MAHOUT_HOME=/home/sgeadmin/mahout
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/conf
```

on the master otherwise none of this works.

So first upload the documents using starclusters put(obviously if you aren't using starcluster skip this :) ):

```
starcluster put mycluster text_train /home/sgeadmin/
starcluster put mycluster text_test /home/sgeadmin/
```

Then we need to add them to hadoop's hbase filesystem (don't forget the -hadoop starcluster):

```
dumbo put /home/sgeadmin/text_train /user/sgeadmin/ -hadoop starcluster
```

Then call Mahout's `seqdirectory` to turn the text into sequence files

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout seqdirectory --input /user/sgeadmin/text_train --output /user/sgeadmin/text_seq -c UTF-8 -ow
```

Then call Mahout's `seq2parse` to turn them into vectors

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout seq2sparse -i text_seq -o /user/sgeadmin/text_vec -wt tf -a org.apache.lucene.analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer -ow
```

Finally call `cvb`, I believe that the `-dt` flag states where the inferred topics should go, but because I haven't yet been able to dump them I can't confirm this.

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout cvb -i /user/sgeadmin/text_vec/tf-vectors -o /user/sgeadmin/text_lda -k 100 -nt 29536 -x 20 -dict /user/sgeadmin/text_vec/dictionary.file-0 -dt /user/sgeadmin/text_cvb_document -mt /user/sgeadmin/text_states
```

The `-k` flag is the number of topics, the `-nt` flag is the size of the dictionary, you can compute this by counting the number of entries of the `dictionary.file-0` inside the vectors(in this case under `/user/sgeadmin/text_vec`) and `-x` is the number of iterations.

If anyone knows how to get what the document topic probabilities are from here, help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
After completing aboveprocess,you can obtain an output of the computed topics using another Mahout utility called LDAPrintTopics.java by passing following commands

--dict (-d) dict  --------->Dictionary to read in, in the same
                                           format as one created by
                                           org.apache.mahout.utils.vectors.lucen
                                           e.Driver
  --output (-o) output--------->Output directory to write top words
  --words (-w) words--------->Number of words to print
  --input (-i) input--------->Path to an LDA output (a state)
  --dictionaryType (-dt) dictionaryType--------->The dictionary file type
                                           (text|sequencefile)
```

Answer (score 2):

The document-topic distribution is stored in sequence file format under the directory you specified with the `-dt` or `--doc_topic_output` when you ran `mahout cvb`.  In your case, this directory will be `/user/sgeadmin/text_cvb_document`

To dump the contents of these sequence files to a text file you can use `mahout vectordump` utility like the following:

```
mahout vectordump -i /path/to/doc_topic_seq_input -o /path/to/doc_topic_text_out -p true -c csv
```

Where:

```
-i    Path to input directory containing document-topic distribution in sequence file format.
-o    Path to output file that will contain your document-topic distribution in text format.
-p    Key values will be displayed if this parameter is used.
-c    Output the Vector as CSV, otherwise it substitutes in the terms for vector cell entries
```